# SQL calculated query for start time and duration to find end time

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my current SQL Select query;

```
SELECT
    Name AS 'Class Name', FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS 'Instructor',
    LessonDuration AS 'Lesson Duration (hrs)', LessonTime AS 'Lesson Start' 
FROM 
    Lesson, Class, Instructor 
WHERE 
    Lesson.ClassID = Class.ClassID 
    AND Lesson.InstructorID = Instructor.InstructorID 
    AND LessonDay = 'Monday' 
ORDER BY 
    LessonTime ASC;
```

I have a table `Lesson` with some columns, but most importantly `LessonDuration` (in hours) and `LessonTime` (which is the start time). In a select query, I would like to have an additional column that displays the end time. This would involve calculating the additional hours put onto the start time using the duration but I am unsure how to do so.

I am using SQL Server built into Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: What if you edit your question and add table structure, sample data and expected results as **formatted text**? It will be great help to help you. So please edit your question.

Comment: Try `DATEADD(hour, LessonDuration, LessonTime) AS EndTime`.

Comment: Brilliant, that seems to have done the trick. Thanks very much.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
SELECT Name AS 'Class Name', FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS 'Instructor',
LessonDuration AS 'Lesson Duration (hrs)', LessonTime AS 'Lesson Start' , DATEADD(HOUR,LessonDuration,LessonTime) 'End Time'
FROM Lesson, Class, Instructor 
WHERE Lesson.ClassID = Class.ClassID 
AND Lesson.InstructorID = Instructor.InstructorID 
AND LessonDay = 'Monday' 
ORDER BY LessonTime ASC;
```